# Box disappears when mouse hovers over it

Tags: support, bug, user-interface

When I hover the mouse over "post your question", that box disappears.
I am using Seamonkey 2.53.6 with Ubuntu Mate 18.04.

It does not occur when using newest Firefox.

Is that normal behavior?
[image]

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot of which 'post your question' item you're referring to?  And what box you're referring to?

Comment: @Thomas Ward Screenshot attached to post.

Comment: Include additional details as well.  Browser you're using, version of that browser, OS you're using that browser in, etc. so that when others dig or try and replicate they will be able to get an idea of if this is just you or a larger UI problem.  I can't replicate it (with my mostly unprivileged sock I use for testing UI issues and such).

Comment: I'm curious: how do you manage to include so much whitespace in all your screenshots? It isn't default for the usual screenshot utilities, so you have to go out of your way to do it. It's quite unfathomable why too.

Comment: I used the default screenshot utility with Ubuntu Mate. And I used Gimp to reduce the file size. @muru

Comment: I found this. https://groups.google.com/g/mozilla.support.seamonkey/c/Ts0u83j6g-E See post by Dirk Fieldhouse.

Comment: Surely GIMP could reduce the size without adding the padding?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by padding? The picture I posted is only a very small section of the screenshot. @muru

Comment: See all the white space in https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkDnx.png?